# How to display list view populated from sqlite data in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating an android application that consists of a list view when a button was clicked list view was populated with the data consisting in sqlite. i did some thing below i am not getting any error but it was not showing any retrieved data.Please help me with this 
This is my activity when a button clicked:

```
fetch_database.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressGenerator.start(fetch_database);
                media_player = media_player.create(DatabaseListView.this, R.raw.retrievingfromdatabase);
                media_player.start();


                String[] from = {logindatabase_adapter.USER_NAME,logindatabase_adapter.USER_PASSWORD};
                int[] to = {R.id.txt_username,R.id.txt_pasword};
                cursor = logindatabase_adapter.feching_Data();
                cursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DatabaseListView.this, R.layout.listcell, cursor, from, to);
                database_results.setAdapter(cursoradapter);
            }
        });
```

This is my logindatabase adapter:

```
package com.developer.milanandroid;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        //Database name
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MilanloginRegistration.db";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="MilanLoginregistration";
        public static final String ID="_id";
        public static final String USER_NAME="USERNAME";
        public static final String USER_PASSWORD ="PASSWORD";


        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME +
                                     "( " +ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+"USERNAME text UNIQUE,"+USER_PASSWORD+" text); ";
        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }



        public void insertEntry(String username,String password)
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

            newValues.put("USERNAME",username);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("MilanLoginregistration",null,newValues);
            ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public int deleteEntry(String username,String password)
        {
            //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
            String where="USERNAME=?";
            int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("MilanLoginregistration", where, new String[]{username,password}) ;
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
        }

        public Cursor feching_Data(){

            String[] columns = {ID,USER_NAME,USER_PASSWORD};
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
            return cursor;

        }
        public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("MilanLoginregistration", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            cursor.close();
            return password;                
        }
        public String checkSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("MilanLoginregistration", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()>=1) // UserName  Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.close();
            return "";              
        }
        public void  updateEntry(String user_name,String pasword)
        {
            // Define the updated row content.
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.  
            updatedValues.put("USERNAME", user_name);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",pasword);


            String where="USERNAME = ?";
            db.update("MilanLoginregistration",updatedValues, where, new String[]{user_name});             
        }   
        /*public void Display(View v){
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from MilanloginRegistration", null);
            admin_settings_child.text_fetched_database_results.setText("");
            c.moveToFirst();
            do{
                String username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
                String password = c.getString(1);
                admin_settings_child.text_fetched_database_results.append("USERNAME::-->"+username+"PASSWORD::-->"+password+"\n");

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a setup in feching_Data that is there in case there is no data or null? Does it move to the First Entry after? Looks like it doesn't, and you should make sure you implement those safe guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I would recommend to use more robust solution with all the recommended building blocks (*cursor adapter, content provider, data loader, ...*) It will save you a lot of grief later. It looks a bit convoluted at the beginning, but it is worth implementing. This approach has been widely publicized elsewhere ([Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html), [Wolfram Rittmeyer](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/tutorials/), [Udacity Class (Lesson 4)](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853) ...)

I put one such solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/seanpjanson/SQListView) and you are free to investigate it (*the attached APK will show how it behaves*). As an added bonus, there is also a PORTRAIT / LANDSCAPE handling with different phone/ tablet layouts.

Good Luck